# how to start or call a function from a different class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

hey guys need to know as of how to start a method in a classA from class B

have

```
 classA(object):
      def __init__(self):
 #this is where the ClassB method'' def multiplyPeople() ''should be called or started.

 classB(object):
     def  multiplyPeople(self):
```

its giving an error

```
  TypeError: unbound method multiplyPeople() must be called 
with classB instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

know this is something basic, but am trying to figure out what exactly is supposed to be done and where am I getting lost.

I have called it as

```
 classA(object):

 def__init__(self):
 self.PeopleVariable=classB.multiplyPeople()
```

Comment: how did you try calling it?

Comment: Can you show more of your code please? With the code you provided, it does not correlate to the error message you provided. Also, the code you provided is not fully functional, as it has syntax errors. Please post your actual code

Comment: you need to create an instance of ``B`` before you can call methods of this class (except you are using static- or classmethods)

Comment: Ca you post an example demonstrating the problem? What you have isn't valid code. Its likely a small tweak on what you are doing. Something like `classB.multipyPeople()` doesn't work because the method requires a class instance. But we can't know for sure until we

Comment: You appear to be calling a *class method directly*, without an instance. Why are you trying to call that mehod? What problem are you trying to solve doing that? What do you expect `self` to bound to in that case?

Comment: @tdelaney have updated the code

Comment: Since we can't tell how these things are used from your example, the minimal fix I can give you is `self.PeopleVariable=classB().multiplyPeople()`. Notice that `classB()` instantiates an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want the function to work. Do you just want to use the class as a placeholder? Then you can use a so called static method for which you do not need to instantiate an object.

Or you can use a regular method and use it on a created object (notice that there you have access to `self`)

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        b = B()
        b.non_static()

        B.multiplyPeople()

class B():
    @staticmethod
    def multiplyPeople():
        print "this was called"

    def non_static(self):
        print self, " was called"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
```

output:

```
<__main__.B instance at 0x7f3d2ab5d710>  was called
this was called
```